# dom childNodes issue

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-node

I seem to be getting different results of fromDate between Mozilla and IE.
Is there a more reliable cross-browser way of doing this? [edit] I am actually getting different column values! [/edit]

```
<tr id='id3332201010241'  />
 <td>20101024</td>
 <td>20101025</td>
 <td>1415</td>
 <td>1445</td>
 <td>INVDROP</td>  
 <td>H4T1A3</td> 
 <td><a href='#' onclick='selectEditActivity("id3332201010241");' >Click Here</a></td>
</tr>

function selectEditActivity(pass_id){ 
 row = document.getElementById(pass_id);    
 var seq = document.getElementById(pass_id).getAttribute("seq");
 var from_date   = row.childNodes[1].innerHTML; 
 alert(from_date);
 var to_date   = row.childNodes[3].innerHTML;  
}
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of the differences you're seeing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the result of differences in how different browsers handle white-space.  Instead (for more general cases) you can use [`getElementsByTagName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName) to for *sure* get a certain type of child element (`<td>` in this case), like this:

```
function selectEditActivity(pass_id){ 
  var row = document.getElementById(pass_id),
      cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td"),
      seq = row.getAttribute("seq"),
      from_date = cells[0].innerHTML,
      to_date = cells[1].innerHTML;  
  alert("From: " + from_date + "\nTo: " + to_date);
}
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/wVPHA/2/).  As @[patrick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/113716/patrick-dw) points out though, it's not needed here, just use the [`.cells`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLTableRowElement) of the `<tr>`, like this:

```
function selectEditActivity(pass_id){ 
  var row = document.getElementById(pass_id),
      seq = row.getAttribute("seq"),
      from_date = row.cells[0].innerHTML,
      to_date = row.cells[1].innerHTML;  
  alert("From: " + from_date + "\nTo: " + to_date);
}
```

[You can test it out here](http://jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/wVPHA/3/).

Comment: You should be able to do it without the `cells = row.getElementsByTagName("td")` since a `<tr>` has its own `cells` property, as in `row.cells[1].innerHTML`.

Comment: @patrick - +1 - *completely* overlooked that here, updated to give the much more efficient version

Answer (score 3):

You wrongly made `<tr>` a self-closing tag

```
<tr id='id3332201010241' />
```

should be

```
<tr id='id3332201010241'>
```

Another thing is that `childNodes` may not work as you expect since it will contain text nodes. If you want to get `<td>` elements in a row you should use:

```
var row       = document.getElementById(pass_id);  
var columns   = row.getElementsByTagName("td"); 
var from_date = columns[1].innerHTML; 
var to_date   = columns[3].innerHTML;
```

> The childNodes nodeList consists of
>   all child nodes of the element,
>   including (empty) text nodes and
>   comment nodes.
>   **[@quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html)**